# Form not being made despite having correct format

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I am new to django and I am trying to load the 'form' variable into the html page
here's the views.py function

```
def show(request):
    showall = Products.objects.all()
    print(showall)
    serializer = POLLSerializer(showall,many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    return render(request,'polls/product_list.html',{"data":serializer.data})
```

below is the insert page where the form

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Edit details of Clothes</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{data}}
            <button class="btn btn-success"><a href="{% url 'polls:show' %}" style="color: red;">Go To Home</a></button>

        </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

the form itself isnt coming,what could the problem be?
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? Why are you passing serializer data to the template and not an actual Django Form?

Comment: I am tasked to use a serializer instead of a form Iain,I also put context = {"data":serializer.data} and then used context.as_p and stilll it didnt come